# Fake ELNA electrolytic smd capacitor

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, electrolytic-capacitor

Few years ago I bought "pack of SMD capacitors", they came only with information about capacitance and voltage. Now I need to use one of them, but I have trouble with find information what exacly they are.

I found RVT series from ELNA, acording to datasheet it should be 12.5x13.5mm, but my are about 7.5x9mm.

Are they fake?

Datasheet: http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/alumi/catalog/pdf/rvt_e.pdf
[image]

Comment: What information about them exactly do you need ? They'll probably work fine as general purpose types, Try them !

Answer (score 4):

The RVT on the caps does not mean it is RVT series capacitor. It is some sort of code which tells something about the caps to the manufacturer, like factory, year, lot, etc.

So you don't have fake Elna RVT capacitors.

If you bought a "pack of capacitors" with only info about capacitance and voltage rating, then you have a pack of random capacitors with no info to determine the manufacturer or any specific information about them.

Comment: The caps he has look nothing like those on the Elna site. http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/alumi/catalog/pdf/rvt_e_p80-81.pdf

Answer (score 3):

They're probably made by [Dongguan Rongqiang Electronics Co., Ltd.](http://www.roqang.com/ProductView.asp?ID=338). Below is a photo of the relevant part in their RVT series of SMD electrolytic capacitors.

Nothing to do with Elna of Japan.

[image]

It's a fairly standard 105°C electrolytic capacitor with leakage maximum 0.01CV + 3uA after 2 minutes (better than some) and tolerance +/-20%.

Answer (score -1):

No are fake, **It are a limited production of capacitors**, that was discontinued to another countries, except china, actually are reselled a new models in amazon and with other caracteristics:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TC7Z26J/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=220uf+16v+capacitor&qid=1602406316&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TC7Z26J)

Actually  Site a sub division of China Store(site.china.cn) are selling it: https://site.china.cn/dianrongqi/4195213960.html

The seller are **Sr. Xia** with the wechat number: 13356460206, are a registered private company, basically of the local market of china, the actual price is: ￥0.35 by unit.

**Here the official store:**
https://www.china.cn/dianrongqi/4195213960.html

Elna are not a official seller, but the products from Sr. Xia, can be reselled.

Elna are not an original fabricant seller, but the products from Sr. Xia, can be reselled because not are manufactured in other countries, are not a international production, only in china it means, you can redistribute with your own mark because not apply any law outside of chine except when are a worldwide trademark, thats why elna can redistribute, amazon buy that by a resellers in this case Tegg.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your broken English. You have found a capacitor made in China that looks like the one in the picture. That doesn't surprise me one bit if they were bought online. As for ... 'Elna are not a official seller', what do you mean by that ? Elna is a well established company making a better than average product.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson His information may well be good. He may mean that Elna do not sell directly but via distributors. (eg Opposite to Nichia who only sell directly (or who did when I dealt with them a while ago)). The parts he noted and the websites may well be relevant.

Comment: I see what you mean. I couldn't make head or tail of what he meant. You may well be correct. His answer is poorly worded.

Comment: @Erkes - Your information is interesting. Can you advise how you know these things. Some people are uncertain about the background to your comments. | Also - I have spent much time in China on product manufacture. I would be interested in any details you can add.